# STM32duino Can bus library

Tags: can-bus, stm32

I couldn't find any library for can bus for STM32duino (Maple Mini) on arduino or even on STMcubeIDE 
I found one library on github but it doesn't compile it has a lot of error (its a fork of the stm32duino github library)

I hope that someone could provide a working library or a simple example on how to implement can bus peripheral on STM32F103